# Clicking Element which is in a <li> element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, html-lists

Hey I am new to Selenium and I am trying to click an Element in a Dropdown Bar but the Error is that "an invalid or illegal selector was specified"

This was my last try:

```
IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"form-participation\"]/div[4]/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]"));
dropdown.Click();
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("//*[@id=\"select2-prize_id-result-ji85-2\"]"));
jsexecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

That was my last try and it didn't work. Thanks for your help in Advance.
I use Selenium in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//*[@id=\"select2-prize_id-result-ji85-2\"]` is not a CSS style locator, it looks like XPath while you trying to use it with `By.CssSelector`
Also it would be better to use `'` instead of `"` inside a string limited by `"` signs. So, I'd suggest your code to be as following:

```
IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='form-participation']/div[4]/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]"));
dropdown.Click();
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='select2-prize_id-result-ji85-2']"));
jsexecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Also, since the second locator is completely based on element ID you could use `By.Id` instead of `By.XPath`, as following:

```
IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='form-participation']/div[4]/div[1]/span/span[1]/span/span[2]"));
dropdown.Click();
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-prize_id-result-ji85-2"));
jsexecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Additionally, `ji85-2` in the last locator may be dynamic value.
I can't check that since you did not share a link to page you working on.
**UPD**
For the first click please try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".select2-selection__arrow")).Click();
```

As about the second element it is dynamic, we need more information about your test flow to understand what element and how to select there.
**UPD**
OK, if, for example, we just want to select the second option in the doplist this can be used:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".select2-selection__arrow")).Click();  
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//li[contains(@class,'select2-results')])[2]")).Click();
```

The index `2` can be changed to 1 or 3 etc accordingly to what option you want to select.
You probably will need to introduce expected condition wait here to make all this work. Or at least, just for beginning, to use sleeps (short delays) between command. But in real code we almost never use hardcoded sleeps.

Comment: Sorry heres the link you have to just jump through the post with the check it button multiple times. https://spiel.spar.at/bbq/?utm_source=spar.at&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=bbq-23#spiel

Comment: Not so clear what element is it and where is it

Comment: When you are at the submit form where you can input your first and last name there is the dropdown and the middle element should be selected

Comment: Okay so as I mentioned I am working with Selenium for about 3 days and I just wanted to try some stuff out. So my plan is to click the check button 14 times to get to the submit form and then enter first- ,lastname ... . Then I have to pick out of the dropbox, after I hit the submit button I thought about doing the same thing again and again so I would put it in a while function. I am really sorry for my lowlevel skills put I am REALLY interested in this topic.

Comment: Thank you for your help this worked perfectly. Thanks for your advice I will look into Explicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

The `select2-prize_id-result-ji85-2id`  looks auto-generated, you should probably look for alternative locators to get to the desired element.

Comment: I tried using CssSelector, Xpatch and ClassName